# Exponential Generating Function for Unordered Binary Trees

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions

Let $b_n$ be the number of all unordered binary trees with n leaves. Then it's known: $$b_n = {1\over 2}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{i}b_ib_{n-i}$$
 Then let $B(x)$ be the $e.g.f $ of $b_n$:

$$B(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n\frac{x^n}{n!}\\=\sum_{n=2}^\infty b_n\frac{x^n}{n!}+x\\=\sum_{n=2}^\infty ({1\over 2}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{i}b_ib_{n-i})\frac{x^n}{n!}+x$$

From here I would like to induce the well-know formula :

$$B(x)=\frac{1}{2}B(x)^2 -x$$

I think I had found the $-x$ part, however, still missing how to induce square form of $B(x)$

Comment: If $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ are two EGFs, compute the coefficients of $A(x) B(x)$, interpreting it as the EGF of a third sequence. It's very strange to me that you're doing problems from a book that talks about EGFs without describing this result; it is absolutely crucial.